# Android Arabic Language Support Problem in Some Devices

Tags: android, android-resources, arabic, samsung-mobile

I'm trying to support the Arabic language. When I changed the language in the application with the following code (refer below), in most of the devices it works fine but in some devices such as `Galaxy S7, Galaxy S8, LG G5` UI transforms to `RTL` successfully but Arabic language resources are not being loaded and the app still uses `EN` string resources.

Has anyone had any opinions about this problem? Thanks for answers.

Here is the code I use for changing language:

```
 private fun updateResources(context: Context, locale: Locale): Context {
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val res = context.resources
        val config = res.configuration
        config.setLocale(locale)
        config.setLayoutDirection(locale)
        BaseActivity.setLayoutDirection(res.configuration.layoutDirection)
        Session.lang = locale.language

        return context.createConfigurationContext(config)
    }
```

Comment: Is this method called in `onConfigurationChanged`?

Answer (score 1):

In your activity, override attachBaseContext function

```
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(updateBaseContextLocale(base))
}
```

updateBaseContextLocale function is like below;

```
private fun updateBaseContextLocale(context: Context): Context {
    val languageCode = LanguageUtils.getLanguageCode(LocalSharedPrefs.getLanguage(context))
    return AppUtils.updateLocale(context, languageCode)
}
```

In AppUtils updateLocale function is like that;

```
@JvmStatic
fun updateLocale(context: Context, languageCode: String): Context {
    val locale = Locale(languageCode)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)

    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        updateResourcesLocale(context, locale)
    } else {
        updateResourcesLocaleLegacy(context, locale)
    }
}

private fun updateResourcesLocaleLegacy(context: Context, locale: Locale): Context {
    val resources = context.resources
    val configuration = resources.configuration
    configuration.locale = locale
    configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale)
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
    return context
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private fun updateResourcesLocale(context: Context, locale: Locale): Context {
    val configuration = context.resources.configuration
    configuration.setLocale(locale)
    configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale)
    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
}
```

I hope your problem can be solved with that answer :)